# Strange LuaLanes behaviour with upvalues

Tags: lua, lua-lanes

I have this code where a function being executed inside [LuaLanes][1] seems to be ignoring to set an upvalue, so I want to know whether this is normal behaviour and I am using it wrong or not.

```
local lanes = require("lanes"):configure()

--A getter/setter module with an upvalue (inlined)
local Common = {}

local internal_variable = {test = 1}

function Common.get_variable()
  print("Using "..tostring(Common).." - Getting var ("..tostring(internal_variable)..") test is "..internal_variable.test)
  return internal_variable
end

function Common.set_variable(new_var)
  print("Using "..tostring(Common).." - Setting var ("..tostring(new_var)..") test is "..new_var.test)
  internal_variable = new_var
  print("Using "..tostring(Common).." - Set     var ("..tostring(internal_variable)..") test is "..internal_variable.test)
end

print("Common ("..tostring(Common)..") initialized")

local function main()
  print("Entering main... Common is "..tostring(Common))
  local var = Common.get_variable()
  print("Inside main var is "..tostring(var))
  local new_var = {test = 2}
  Common.set_variable(new_var)
  local verify_var = Common.get_variable()
  print("Inside main new var is "..tostring(verify_var))
  assert(new_var == verify_var)
end

print("Starting program... Common is "..tostring(Common))

local result
--result = main()
result = lanes.gen("*",main)()[1]
```

When run with Lanes, the assertion fails, but runs just fine (as expected) running just `main()`.

Output using `main()`:

```
Common (table: 00000000006E9DD0) initialized
Starting program... Common is table: 00000000006E9DD0
Entering main... Common is table: 00000000006E9DD0
Using table: 00000000006E9DD0 - Getting var (table: 00000000006E9E20) test is 1
Inside main var is table: 00000000006E9E20
Using table: 00000000006E9DD0 - Setting var (table: 00000000006EA140) test is 2
Using table: 00000000006E9DD0 - Set     var (table: 00000000006EA140) test is 2
Using table: 00000000006E9DD0 - Getting var (table: 00000000006EA140) test is 2
Inside main new var is table: 00000000006EA140
```

Output using `lanes.gen("*",main)()[1]`

```
Common (table: 0000000000719480) initialized
Starting program... Common is table: 0000000000719480
Entering main... Common is table: 0000000000740800
Using table: 0000000000740800 - Getting var (table: 00000000007408A0) test is 1
Inside main var is table: 00000000007408A0
Using table: 0000000000740800 - Setting var (table: 0000000000740A80) test is 2
Using table: 0000000000740800 - Set     var (table: 0000000000740A80) test is 2
Using table: 0000000000740800 - Getting var (table: 00000000007408A0) test is 1
Inside main new var is table: 00000000007408A0
F:\dev\Env\Lua\lua51-lua-5.1.4-x64\bin\lua.exe: ...\LanesBehaviourTest\LanesBehaviour\src\main\main.lua:29: assertion failed!
stack traceback:
    [C]: ?
    [C]: ?
    ...\LanesBehaviourTest\LanesBehaviour\src\main\main.lua:36: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

Why is it that `get_variable()` returns the same table even after being set another? Any ideas?

PS: Also, probably related, why is it that Common changes when run inside lanes? Does it get entirely copied over to the new lane Lua state?

```
  [1]: https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes
```

Comment: What does all that debugging information say in both the cases?

Comment: I updated question to better clarify!

Comment: Yes. The tables are quite likely copied entirely. I believe this is what the `linda` stuff is all about is it not?

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't `linda` only a submodule used for inter-lane communication?

Comment: And isn't "inter-lane communication" **exactly** what you are trying to accomplish here?